# Поменять местами значения элементов, находящихся на нечетных позициях, с правым соседом

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста. Я написала код для задачи, где надо Поменять местами значения элементов, находящихся на нечетных позициях, с правым соседом. Но программа выдает ошибку компиляции не могу понять в чём проблема.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0; i<2*n; i++)
        cin>>a[i];
    for(int i=0; i<((2*n)-1); i+=2){
         int b=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i+1];
            a[i+1]=b;
           cout<<a[i]<<" ";
           cout<<a[i+1]<<" ";
    }
}
```

Ввод:
2 3 4 6 8 21
Вывод:3 2 6 4 21 8 -856850045 -608398848 0 0 21987 -1800889904 32764 -1002209536 0 0 (-856850045 -608398848 0 0 21987 -1800889904 32764 -1002209536 0 0-эти символы лишние)

Comment: Вы путаете *ошибку компиляции* и неверную работу программы. *Ошибок компиляции* у вас нет: https://ideone.com/QvICYL А одна из первых же проблем — что у вас массив на `n` элементов, а пишете вы в него `2n` элементов. Вы никогда не пытались влезть в джинсы на 4 размера меньше? Неуютно, правда? Вот так и вашим данным...

Comment: Да, что считать у вас нечетными позициями? Во что должен превратиться массив 1 2 3 4 5 6 — в 1 3 2 5 4 6, или в 2 1 4 3 6 5?

Comment: @Harry извините конечно, но сайт называет это ошибкой компиляции

Comment: См. по приведенной мною ссылке: где там вы видите "ошибка компиляции"? А "Ошибка выполнения" есть. https://i121.fastpic.org/big/2023/0324/17/2685b3c311228c0aa4247a4a70d3e517.jpg

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от того, что ответите на вопрос Harry, оставьте строку `#define  _132546` как есть или закомментируйте ее.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define  _132546

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int* a = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];

    for (int i =
#if defined(_132546)
                1;
#else
                0;
#endif
            i + 1 < n; i += 2) {
        int b = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i + 1];
        a[i + 1] = b;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << a[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;

    delete[] a;
    }
```

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Если вы довольны ответом, то на ruSO предлагают голосовать за него кликом мышкой на треугольнике вверх слева от ответа. Такие клики возможны для каждого ответа. Один ответ, наиболее полный, отмечается как принятый - кликом на птичке слева - это значит, что вы полностью удовлетворены и новые ответы не ждете. Читайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help